# Как сделать самому scroll hijacking?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать scroll hijacking, как на этом сайте https://neematic.com ?
Нашел кучу плагинов, но хотелось бы понять как оно работает.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Пример красивый, вопрос вроде интересный. Но вопрос на столько обширный, там столько деталей...  Тебе надо привести минимальный самодостаточный пример...  Указать, что ты сделал, что у тя не получилось, с какими проблемами столкнулся... Не верстать же пример с нуля для тебя...

Comment: @Air, абсолютно согласен. Мне просто необходимо понять направление, в котором двигаться. Как я понял, мы ставим на body "overflow: hidden", после этого у нас перестает работать событие на scroll, мы всем тегам <section> ставим абсолютное позиционирование,  и ставим собитие на onmousewheel,  и при прокрутке мы меняем расположение наших секций с помощью "transform: translateX()". Просто хочу понять, в правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: Aleksander, ну  body "overflow: hidden", это еще цветочки....  Там столько всего и столько мелочей... Но на само деле, это очень легко, когда понимаешь как это работает...  Посмотри уроки js, почитай, или используй готовый плагин. На счет плагина я тебе не советчик, скажу честно, никогда ничего чужого не использовал...

Comment: Посмотрите https://c o d e p e n.io/smongey/pen/CLzkb как вариант для анализа реализации